# Does Windows Azure supports Infiniband on Linux VM?

Tags: azure, infiniband

1. Is the lack of RDMA a reason ([source1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn689095.aspx), [source2](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/14/new-a8a9-virtual-machine-sizes/)) for problems with a network, e.g. ifconfig displays eth1-avahi (see [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3159/delete-eth0-avahi-from-the-ifconfig-list))? I want to run OpenFOAM on two A8 nodes and have to do

   /etc/init.d/networking restart

frequently to enable just eth0. Otherwise mpi uses wrong IP address to communicate, e.g. 169... , instead of 10.....

```
$bash> ifconfig
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:0d:3a:20:3f:33
inet addr:10.0.0.4 Bcast:10.0.1.255 Mask:255.255.254.0

eth1 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:15:5d:33:ff:ad
inet6 addr: fe80::215:5dff:fe33:ffad/64 Scope:Link

eth1:avahi Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:15:5d:33:ff:ad
inet addr:169.254.9.198 Bcast:169.254.255.255 Mask:255.255.0.0
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
```

2. If I run mpirun with Infiniband as follows:

   mpirun --host localhost --mca btl openib,self,tcp -np $nProcs

is it really Infiniband on the VM?

Comment: Infiniband is only on an A8 or A9 instance. Are you running your tests on one of these sizes?

Comment: Yes. I am running on two A8 instances.